# Storage.BlobListOption.pageSize GCS not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to get fixed number of blobs in one call and I am using below `.list` call arguments on `storage` object.

```
        Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
        Page<Blob> blobs = storage.list(bucketName,
                Storage.BlobListOption.prefix(id1 + "/" + id2 + "/" + "request/"),
                Storage.BlobListOption.startOffset("id1/id2/request/123"),
                Storage.BlobListOption.pageSize(5)
        );
```

But it is listing all the results(~200)

```
id1/id2/request/123/
id1/id2/request/234/
id1/id2/request/789/
----
----
----
```

#### Environment

- Java 11
- com.google.cloud
    google-cloud-storage
    2.20.1

How do I make pageSize() function work ?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your environment and the code you are using.

Comment: Updated the question @Chanpols let me know if you need any other specific details.

Comment: Can you provide more information for your iteration/looping. Thanks